# Batched queries with SQL Server Compact 4.0 and alternatives if unsupported?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-ce, sql-injection

I'm trying to execute a query which contains "batched" commands, and supposedly this wasn't supported by Compact 3.5, however I want to avoid using SQL Express or a bigger solution that makes deployment on desktops cumbersome.

For example:

```
String query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [Mytable] WHERE [Id] = 2; DROP TABLE...");
SqlCeCommand cmd= new SqlCeCommand(query , db.Connection);
```

The application is a testbed for common .NET secure development problems, so I need to support batched queries in order to support SQL injection issues. Funny as it gets, I can't just roll a huge deployment burden for an entire class of students and make each one of them install SQL Server Express.

Any comments appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsupported... I moved the code base to SQLite3. Works like a charm. Considering it's public domain I would recommend people using Compact to ditch it for SQLite!